# Finding a file in a Python module distribution

Tags: python, distutils

I've written a Python package that includes a bsddb database of pre-computed values for one of the more time-consuming computations.  For simplicity, my setup script installs the database file in the same directory as the code which accesses the database (on Unix, something like /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mypackage/).

How do I store the final location of the database file so my code can access it?  Right now, I'm using a hack based on the `__file__` variable in the module which accesses the database:

```
dbname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "database.dat")
```

It works, but it seems... hackish.  Is there a better way to do this?  I'd like to have the setup script just grab the final installation location from the distutils module and stuff it into a "dbconfig.py" file that gets installed alongside the code that accesses the database.

Comment: Minimal runnable published working example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed/60735402#60735402

Answer (score 36):

Try using pkg_resources, which is part of setuptools (and available on all of the pythons I have access to right now):

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, "foo.config")
'foo.config'
>>> pkg_resources.resource_filename('tempfile', "foo.config")
'/usr/lib/python2.4/foo.config'
```

There's more discussion about using pkg_resources to get resources on the [eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources) page and the [pkg_resources](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources) page.

Also note, where possible it's probably advisable to use pkg_resources.resource_stream or pkg_resources.resource_string because if the package is part of an egg, resource_filename will copy the file to a temporary directory.

Comment: This makes your package depend on `setuptools`, which is not present in standard library.

Comment: @techtonik Sadly, the two standard ways to access resources are using disutils or setuptools. There is no decent way to access resources in a module using only the standard libraries. This is partly due to the fact that it is hard to build a widely distributable module without external libraries.

Comment: This is now the righ answer since setuptools is part pip and recent Python have ensure_pip.

Comment: Not anymore.  Since Python-3.7 the standard way is to use `importlib.resources` standard library's  module.

Answer (score 20):

Use `pkgutil.get_data`. It’s the cousin of `pkg_resources.resource_stream`, but in the standard library, and should work with flat filesystem installs as well as zipped packages and other importers.

Comment: I strongly prefer this over using pkg_resources, since pkgutil is always available, and because pkg_resources seems to trigger unpacking a zipped egg in the $PYTHON_EGG_CACHE directory, which kind of defeats the purpose of having zipped eggs...

Answer (score 3):

That's probably the way to do it, without resorting to something more advanced like using setuptools to install the files where they belong.

Notice there's a problem with that approach, because on OSes with real a security framework (UNIXes, etc.) the user running your script might not have the rights to access the DB in the system directory where it gets installed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the standard Python-3.7 library's [`importlib.resources` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#module-importlib.resources), 
which is [more efficient](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#example) than [`setuptools:pkg_resources`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access)
(on previous Python versions, use the backported [`importlib_resources` library](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html)).

**Attention:** For this to work, the folder where the data-file resides *must be a regular python-package*.  That means you must add an `__init__.py` file into it, if not already there.

Then you can access it like this:

```py
try:
  import importlib.resources as importlib_resources
except ImportError:
  # In PY<3.7 fall-back to backported `importlib_resources`.
  import importlib_resources


## Note that the actual package could have been used, 
#  not just its (string) name, with something like: 
#      from XXX import YYY as data_pkg
data_pkg = '.'
fname = 'database.dat'

db_bytes = importlib_resources.read_binary(data_pkg, fname)
# or if a file-like stream is needed:
with importlib_resources.open_binary(data_pkg, fname) as db_file:
    ...
```