# MANIFEST.in ignored on "python setup.py install" - no data files installed?

Tags: python, build, installation, distutils

Here's my stripped-down setup.py script with non-code stuff removed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from whyteboard.misc import meta


setup(
    name = 'Whyteboard',
    version = meta.version,

    packages = ['whyteboard', 'whyteboard.gui', 'whyteboard.lib', 'whyteboard.lib.pubsub',
                'whyteboard.lib.pubsub.core', 'whyteboard.lib.pubsub.utils', 'whyteboard.misc'],

    py_modules = ['whyteboard'],
    scripts = ['whyteboard.py'],
)
```

MANIFEST.in:

```
include *.txt
include whyteboard-help/*.*
recursive-include locale *.mo
recursive-include images *.png
```

When I run "python setup.py install sdist" I get a nice .tar.gz with a "whyteboard-0.41" root folder, with my locale/ images/ and whyteboard-help/ folders inside. This also has my whyteboard.py script that launches my program from inside the whyteboard source package.

So:

```
whyteboard/
 ├── locale/
 ├── images
 ├── whyteboard-help/
 ├── whyteboard/
 │  ├── __init__.py
 │  └── other packages etc
 ├── whyteboard.py
 ├── README
 ├── setup.py
 └── CHANGELOG
```

This mirrors the source of my program, is how everything should be, and is correct.

However when I run "python setup.py install" none of my data files are written - only the "whyteboard" source package, and the whyteboard.py is placed in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/.

Ideally, I'd like the same directory structure as what's been generated in the .tar.gz file to be created in dist-packages, as this is how my program expects to look for its resources.

How can I get "install" to create this directory structure? It seems to be ignoring my manifest file, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Related: [How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522250/674039)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Some notes in addition to Ned's answer (which hits on the core problem):

Distutils does not install Python packages and modules inside a per-project subdirectory within `site-packages` (or `dist-packages` on Debian/Ubuntu): they are installed directly into `site-packages`, as you've seen. So the containing `whyteboard-xx` directory in your sdist will not exist in the final installed form.

One implication of this is that you should be careful to name your `data_files` in a way that clarifies what project they belong to, because those files/directories are installed directly into the global `site-packages` directory, not inside any containing `whyteboard` directory.

Or you could instead make your data `package_data` of the `whyteboard` package (which means it needs to live inside that package, i.e. next to `__init__.py`), and then this isn't a problem.

Lastly, it doesn't make much sense to have both a `whyteboard.py` module in `py_modules` and a `whyteboard/__init__.py` package in `packages`. The two are mutually exclusive, and if you have both, the `whyteboard.py` module will be ignored by imports in favor of the package of the same name.

If `whyteboard.py` is just a script, and is not intended to be imported, then you should use the [scripts](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) option for it, and remove it from `py_modules`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I don't like the idea of having package data - to me, it makes more sense for those resources to live outside of the source directory. Nor do I like having to have directory names prefixed with the program name (even though I already do that for the help files). Hmm..

Answer (score 73):

`MANIFEST.in` tells Distutils what files to include in the source distribution but it does not directly affect what files are installed.  For that you need to include the appropriate files in the `setup.py` file, generally either as [package data](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) or as [additional files](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files).

Comment: I tried adding a list of package data but none of the files I specified were used. I wasn't sure whether the locations of the files were installed relative to the overall installation of the package. Anyhow, it still wasn't writing my files in the correct directory structure I expected.

Comment: The documentation linked in this answer gives you all the information you need about where data_files and package_data are installed. If these options aren't working for you, please update your question with the exact syntax you tried, the results, and what you expected.

Comment: This works for me: Duplicating my MANIFEST.in entries inside setup.py's data_packages makes everything work. Thanks Ned - I have failed to understand this point for years. Hopefully now my distutils/setuptools/distribute experiences will make more sense.

Comment: Does this design of being able to include files in the package that will not get installed make sense? When would it be used?

Answer (score 40):

I couldn't figure out why my `MANIFEST.in` file was being ignored when I ran `python setup.py install` - turns out `include_package_data=True` solves the problem. The `package_data` option isn't actually required.

Comment: good catch, why `include_package_data=True` is not default value?

Answer (score 10):

You should use setuptools:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from whyteboard.misc import meta


setup(
  name = 'Whyteboard',
  version = meta.version,

  packages = find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True,

  py_modules = ['whyteboard'],
  scripts = ['whyteboard.py'],
)
```

This is not actually using the MANIFEST file to do the job, but it includes all the needed files.

Comment: This did work for me with **setuptools**. I build Debian package and I see my glade files listed in `package_data` dictionary appear in the right place only after I added `include_package_data=Tru`.

Answer (score 8):

Running python 2.6.1 on Mac OSX, I had absolutely no luck except by using the **data_files** parameter in setup.py. Everything with MANIFEST.in simply resulted in files being included in the dist package, but never installed. I checked some other packages and they were indeed using data_files to specify additional files.

I created a short function to help enumerate all the files from a directory tree in the

**(target_dir, [file list])** format that data_files expects:

```
def gen_data_files(*dirs):
    results = []

    for src_dir in dirs:
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src_dir):
            results.append((root, map(lambda f:root + "/" + f, files)))
    return results
```

Now I can just call this inside my setup call:

```
setup(... data_files = gen_data_files("docs", "lib") ...
```

And everything in those trees gets installed.

Comment: This is great, but where does it get installed to? For me, when using "pip install", my data_files go into the root of my virtualenv (ie. a single directory shared by all the virtualenv's packages.) If using "setup.py install", then my data_files go into "site-packages/<mypackage>.egg/". If the files are data needed at runtime, then in neither case is it trivial for my code to find these files, and of course I have to search both directories at runtime. If the files are my LICENSE file, then in neither case is it trivial for my users get from my source to the LICENSE. Puzzled.

Answer (score 6):

**Minimal published runnable example**

- https://github.com/cirosantilli/python-sample-package-with-data
- https://pypi.org/project/python-sample-package-with-data

Key takeaway: only `MANIFEST.in` worked for me, `package_data` did not.

Tested on Ubuntu 19.10, Python 3.7.5, wheel==0.32.3, setuptools==41.1.0, twine==3.1.1.

How end users use the package from https://pypi.org/project/python-sample-package-with-data/:

```
python3 -m pip install --user python-sample-package-with-data
python-sample-package-with-data
```

Expected output:

```
hello data
```

How maintainers publish it:

```
# One time setup.
python3 -m pip install --user setuptools wheel twine

# Every time you want to publish.
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
rm -rf build dist *.egg-info
```

The actual files:

MANIFEST.in

```
# Or else pip install cannot find README.md on the setup.py under certain conditions.
include README.md

# This actually adds the data file.
include python_sample_package_with_data/mydata.txt
```

python-sample-package-with-data

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import python_sample_package_with_data

print(python_sample_package_with_data.get_data(), end='')
```

python_sample_package_with_data/__init__.py

```
try:
    import importlib.resources as importlib_resources
except ImportError:
    # In PY<3.7 fall-back to backported `importlib_resources`.
    import importlib_resources

def get_data():
    return importlib_resources.read_text(__name__, 'mydata.txt')
```

python_sample_package_with_data/mydata.txt

```
hello data
```

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

from os import path
this_directory = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
with open(path.join(this_directory, 'README.md')) as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='python-sample-package-with-data',
    version='0.0.3',
    description='My short description',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/cirosantilli/python-sample-package-with-data',
    author='Ciro Santilli',
    author_email='ciro.santilli.contact@gmail.com',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    scripts=['python-sample-package-with-data'],
)
```

Bibliography:

- [How do I distribute my pip package with data files correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577762/how-do-i-distribute-my-pip-package-with-data-files-correctly)
- [Python pkg_resources and file access in packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817944/python-pkg-resources-and-file-access-in-packages)
- [Finding a file in a Python module distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104/finding-a-file-in-a-python-module-distribution)
- [Any python function to get "data_files" root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211575/any-python-function-to-get-data-files-root-directory)
- [MANIFEST.in, package_data, and data_files clarification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422340/manifest-in-package-data-and-data-files-clarification)
- [setup.py not installing data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235820/setup-py-not-installing-data-files)