# Installing data files into site-packages with setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a Python package with a standard setup.py installer but I cannot for the life of me get it to install some pre-defined configuration files into site-packages somewhere... my setup() function is called like this:

```
setup(
  name='Hydrant',
  version=version,
  description=long_description,
  author='Scott Frazer',
  author_email='scott.d.frazer@gmail.com',
  packages=['hydrant'],
  package_data={'hydrant': ['sql/*.sql', 'hydrant.conf', 'hydrant.deploy']},
  data_files=[('config', ['hydrant/hydrant.conf'])],
  install_requires=[
    "xtermcolor>=1.0.3",
    "pyyaml",
    "pymysql",
    "jprops"
  ],
  entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
      'hydrant = hydrant.Main:Cli'
    ]
  },
  test_suite='hydrant.test',
  license = "MIT",
)
```

I was experimenting around with `package_data` and `data_files` but they simply don't seem to DO anything.  I'm installing into a virtual environment with the command line:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including non-Python files with setup.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `MANIFEST.in` file to your module. Althought AFAIK it's only used to add data to generated packages (eggs or tar.gz distribution files)
Look at this [StackOverflow related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597263/236871).

Others programmers made it work switching to distutils, but i wouldn't recommend it since it's deprecated by distribute.
Look at this [other StackOverflow related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522621/236871)