# MANIFEST.in, package_data, and data_files clarification?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to create a Python package, and I have a directory structure like this:

```
mypkg/
├── __init__.py
├── module1
│   ├── x.py
│   ├── y.py
│   └── z.txt
└── module2
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
```

Then I added all the files in `MANIFEST.in` and when I check the created archive, it had all the files.

When I do `python setup.py install` in the `dist-packages/mypkg/module1`. I see only the Python files and not `z.txt`.

I have `z.txt` in both `MANIFEST.in` and `setup.py`:

```py
setup (
    packages = [
        'mypkg',
        'mypkg.module1',
        'mypkg.module2',
    ],
    package_data = {
        'mypkg': ['module1/z.txt']
    },
    include_package_data = True, 
    ...
)
```

I tried adding the file as `data_files` as well but that created a directory in `/usr/local`. I want to keep it inside the source code directory as the code uses that data.

I have read the posts listed below but I keep getting confused about what is the right way to keep `z.txt` in the right location after `setup.py install`.

- [MANIFEST.in ignored on "python setup.py install" - no data files installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed/3597263#3597263)
- [Installing data files into site-packages with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689816/installing-data-files-into-site-packages-with-setup-py)
- http://blog.codekills.net/2011/07/15/lies,-more-lies-and-python-packaging-documentation-on--package_data-/

Comment: Update: 

It got fixed when I started using setuptools instead of distutils.core. I think it was some problem with distutils not agreeing with manifest while setuptools worked without any changes in the code. 

I recommend using setuptools in the future. Using the link [here][1].


  [1]: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#developer-s-guide

Comment: Minimal runnable published working example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed/60735402#60735402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: It got fixed when I started using setuptools instead of distutils.core. I think it was some problem with distutils not agreeing with manifest while setuptools worked without any changes in the code. I recommend using setuptools in the future. Using the link [here : setup tools- developers guide](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#developer-s-guide)

Answer (score 14):

Try using setuptools instead of distutils.