# After installation of Python package from Git repository some folders are missing

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I want to install a package from the following repo https://github.com/geomin/django-countria.
The command I'm using is `pip install git://github.com/geomin/django-countria.git`. Pip clones the repo to a temporary folder and then runs `setup.py`. The problem is that after installation completes, `site_packages` containes files `countria-0.8-py2.7.egg/countria/models.py` and `countria-0.8-py2.7.egg/countria/__init__.py` but no `fixtures` and `locale` folders. If I clone the package and run `setup.py` I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The reason the package misses fixtures and stuff is that there is no [MANIFEST](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/MANIFEST.in) in this repo.

Try installing for development:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/geomin/django-countria.git#egg=countria
```

Or, clone the package and run:

```
pip install -e path/to/clone
```

Answer (score 1):

It's correct that I can install the package in development mode but since I need to work in a version control system without versioning the src/ folder I need to make it work using pip.
I tried with a MANIFEST.in file but it seems that MANIFEST either is not working properly between differrent python version or it does not dirrectly affect the files to be installed.
So the solution is to add the desired files in setup.py as package data ar additional files.
http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data
Related question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597263/812501