# How can I install from a git subdirectory with pip?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a git repository with many folders, one of them being a python module installable with pip, like this:

```
repo.git/
repo.git/folder1/
repo.git/folder2/
repo.git/mymodule/
repo.git/mymodule/__init__.py
repo.git/mymodule/setup.py
repo.git/mymodule/...
```

Right now I have to do the following to install:

```
git clone http://server/repo.git
cd repo
pip install mymodule
cd ..
rm -rf repo
```

Is it possible to install the module directly with pip without explicitly cloning ?

I tried:

```
pip install git+https://server/repo.git/mymodule/
pip install git+https://server/repo.git:mymodule/
```

But I get:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-88tlLm-build/setup.py'
```

Comment: This question seems to already be answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847764/pip-install-from-git-repo

Comment: The question you linked was about missing files because there's no MANIFEST.in. My question is about how to install a subdirectory with pip, no files are missing since I can install the package by cloning the whole repo.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel The question you linked to asks about different thing but the title was misleading so I corrected it. You can consider removing your (I guess) downvote.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1215) regarding this feature, and it seems to have been merged to develop branch a month ago. The syntax is the [following](https://github.com/pnasrat/pip/commit/abf27b5bd207024b35885fd1fddd7803b488a3d4):

```
pip install -e "git+https://git.repo/some_repo.git#egg=$NAME_OF_PACKAGE&subdirectory=$SUBDIR_IN_REPO" # install a python package from a repo subdirectory
```

We probably have to wait for a while until it gets merged to master and is distributed.

**UPDATE**: This is now available and documented at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#vcs-support as follows:

> For projects where setup.py is not in the root of project,
> "subdirectory" component is used. Value of "subdirectory" component
> should be a path starting from root of the project to where setup.py
> is located.
>
> So if your repository layout is:
>
> ```
> - pkg_dir/
>   - setup.py  # setup.py for package ``pkg``
>   - some_module.py
> - other_dir/
>   - some_file
> - some_other_file
> ```
>
> You'll need to use
>
> ```
> pip install -e "vcs+protocol://repo_url/#egg=pkg&subdirectory=pkg_dir"
> ```

**Note**: Make sure to surround it with quotes otherwise subdirectory won't work.

Comment: I just checked and it is part of pip v1.5, released Jan 1 2014: https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/CHANGES.txt

Comment: [Specific changelog entry](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/54de36d9aee18b23379cd417dcc6ede3c0d93f96/CHANGES.txt#L57) in pip v1.5 where this feature was merged.

Comment: This is in theory what I want, but I can't seem to get it to work with git+ssh or git+https, even though I have pip version 1.5.6 working with Python 3.4. I get the error, `'subdirectory' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: If you are using ubuntu make sure to use single quotation marks before the actual git location, otherwise the &subdirectory is ignored!
For example: pip install -e 'git+https://git.repo/some_repo.git#egg=version_subpkg&subdirectory=version_subpkg'

Comment: Just a heads-up: this does not seem to work (at least on pip v1.5.6, not sure about 6+ versions) for packages whose *entry points* lie within the subdirectory. `pip install -e 'git+https://…/repo.git@branch#egg=package&subdirectory=package'` results in the package *appearing* to install, and a `package.egg-link` file getting put in site-packages — but it points to the root directory of `src/repo`, *not* to `src/repo/package`, as I would expect. This means that `py_modules` can’t be imported, and `entry_points` don’t actually work: they both raise an `ImportError: No module named package`.

Comment: `-e` seems necessary, otherwise `pip freeze` doesn't show the whole path, only the egg. This happened on `pip-1.5.4`

Comment: tip for others: you HAVE to use git+https, git+git will not work, you'll get 

    fatal: remote error: 
    Repository not found.

presumably because it doesn't parse the "query" string correctly.  I've just logged: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4898

Comment: Another tip for others: On Windows, you must place the URL in double quotes, or you'll get an error "'subdirectory' is not recognized as an internal or external command". E.g., use: pip install -e "git+myurl/proj#egg=subpkg&subdirectory=subdir"

Comment: @JohnPirie thanks! Feel free to update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Updated link to documentation for PIP: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#url-fragments

Answer (score 48):

It's been already stated in [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566200/how-can-i-install-from-a-git-subdirectory-with-pip/50930840#comment42223717_19516714) under the correct answer, but just to highlight this issue: when executing this from Linux command line, you **must** escape the `&`-character since ampersand is telling the command line to run a command in background:

```
git+https://git.repo/some_repo.git#egg=version_subpkg\&subdirectory=repo
```

Notice the backslash before the ampersand. The escaping behaviour might depend on the Linux distro; I'm not an expert.
If you ignore this, you might run into a cryptic error like the following:

```
bash: (...) command not found
```

Comment: Would enclosing the url in single quotes help avoid the need for escaping the ampersand? I know that is helpful when working with URLs in cURL.

Comment: Also worth noting:  When executing this from Windows command line, you must place the URL in double quotes, or you'll get an error "'subdirectory' is not recognized as an internal or external command".  E.g., use pip install -e "git+https://myurl/proj#egg=subpkg&subdirectory=subdir"

Comment: In general, when working with shell scripts, use double quotes around arguments to be on the safe side.   for more best practices see: https://www.shellcheck.net/ or https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

Comment: The escaping is necessary in OSX as well (as it is a sort of Linux distro)

Comment: For branch-based install use: `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/org_or_username/repo.git@branch#subdirectory=path/to/dubdir`

Answer (score 4):

The [latest docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#url-fragments) discourage the use of the `#egg=pkg` URL fragment.
Instead, they suggest to use only the subdirectory fragment:

For example, if your package `pkg` is in subdirectory `pkg_dir`:

```
python -m pip install "pkg @ git+https://git@github.com/org/repo.git#subdirectory=pkg_dir"
```

Note that `pkg @` seems optional, at least for `pyproject.toml` projects.

Comment: This is just what I needed, thanks a lot for the answer, missed it in the docs.

Comment: Instead of egg, you can also use `tag=...` to install the version you want based on tag.