# pip install from a subdirectory of git repo in non-editable mode

Tags: python, git, pip

The following works fine:

```
user@host ~/test> pip install -e 'git+http://git.mydomain.com/project.git#egg=project-sdk&subdirectory=sdk/python'
```

But the following fails:

```
user@host ~/test> pip install 'git+http://git.mydomain.com/project.git#egg=project-sdk&subdirectory=sdk/python'
Collecting project from git+http://git.mydomain.com/project.git#egg=project-sdk&subdirectory=sdk/python
Cloning git+http://git.mydomain.com/project.git to /tmp/160806751.tmpdir/pip-build-XR8vJn/project-sdk
remote: Counting objects: 180, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (135/135), done.
remote: Total 180 (delta 46), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (180/180), 52.71 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (46/46), done.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/160806751.tmpdir/pip-build-XR8vJn/project-sdk/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/160806751.tmpdir/pip-build-XR8vJn/project-sdk
```

I want to install some packages directly from a git repo - they are not available on PyPI. Since I am not going to edit them, there is no point in using the editable mode. The problem is that the root of the git contains multiple directories, not all of which contain python code. So it doesn't make sense to have the setup.py in the root directory.

I am using pip 7.1.2.

```
user@host ~/test> pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /home/user/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
user@host ~/test>
```

So the question is - is there a way to install a package using pip from a subdirectory of a git repository **in non-editable mode**?

Before someone points out, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566200/install-from-a-git-subdirectory-with-pip) question doesn't contain the answer to how to install in **non-editable** mode.