# install from a git subdirectory with pip requirements

Tags: python, git, pip

I have the following structure in git

```
scripts/
scripts/folder1/
scripts/folder1/module
scripts/folder1/module/setup.py
scripts/folder1/module/src/module
scripts/folder1/module/src/module/__init__.py
scripts/folder1/module/src/module/source.py
```

I want to install module , so I tried the following in my requirements.txt

```
git+https://user@bitbucket.org/repo-name/scripts.git#egg=module&subdirectory=module
```

but this does not seem to work and I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/p_/gz96g4610fn94hz6w_l2gjyw0000gn/T/pip-build-MLhekq/module/module/setup.py
```

I understand that this question may have been answered at [How can I install from a git subdirectory with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566200/how-can-i-install-from-a-git-subdirectory-with-pip) but I am looking for the exact syntax in my case.

Answer (score 12):

ok, just figured out this. For anyone who may spend hours on this

```
git+https://user@bitbucket.org/repo-name/scripts.git#subdirectory=folder1/module
```

Comment: what about the egg name? `#egg=mypackage`

Comment: If you are on Windows in a `cmd.exe`, you will want to escape the `&` with a `^` sign. Like so: `pip install git+https://user@bitbucket.org/repo-name/scripts.git#egg=my_package^&subdirectory=folder1/module`

Comment: tip for others: you HAVE to use git+https, git+git will not work, you'll get 

    fatal: remote error: 
    Repository not found.

presumably because it doesn't parse the "query" string correctly.  I've just logged: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4898