# pip installing a local file gives me error

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, open3d

I am trying to install Open3D from https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/tree/master/python because I would like to edit the code therefore I am not installing Open3D from PyPI. I downloaded the file from github to my local files and ran `pip install Downloads/Open3D/python`. I ran the installation under the `python` subdirectory because it contain setup.py and requirements.txt. However when I run the command `pip install Downloads/Open3D/python`, I get this error.

```
Processing c:\users\md fardin nahid\downloads\open3d\python
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      C:\Users\MDFARD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-35qkg2d4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      error in @PYPI_PACKAGE_NAME@ setup command: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried directly installing from the github using `pip install "git+https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D.git"` which did not work because the directory did not contain setup.py or pyproject.toml.

Anyone know how I can fix this issue? or anyone know any other ways I am able to download Open3D from github so that I can edit the code? I am using anaconda. I am new to this package stuff. Thanks.

Windows 11
pip 22.2.2
python 3.7.15
git version 2.38.1.1

Comment: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/compilation.html has instructions on building from source.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566200 answer your question?