Can I have two Libraries within one Azure Repo and install them using requirements.txt
I have a Repo with two libraries committed. Basically two folder containing different libraries within one single repo. And I want this libraries to be installed using requirements.txt. Is this possible?
django-auth-adfs @ git+https://{username}:{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}/django-auth-adfs@main#egg=django-auth-adfs

django @ git+https://{username}:{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}/django@main#egg=django

I found this command to put within requirements.txt but this throws errors while installing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516714/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+subdirectory

Try this in your requirements.txt:
django-auth-adfs @ git+https://{username}:{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}@main#egg=django-auth-adfs&subdirectory=django-auth-adfs

django @ git+https://{username}:{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}@main#egg=django&&subdirectory=django

See the docs at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/
