# setup.py not installing data files

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils

I have a Python library that, in addition to regular Python modules, has some data files that need to go in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/mylibrary.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to convince setup.py to actually install the data files there. Note that this behaviour is under install - not sdist.

Here is a slightly redacted version of setup.py

```
module_list = list_of_files

setup(name         ='Modules',
      version      ='1.33.7',
      description  ='My Sweet Module',
      author       ='PN',
      author_email ='email',
      url          ='url',
      packages     = ['my_module'],

# I tried this. It got installed in /usr/my_module. Not ok.

      # data_files   = [ ("my_module",  ["my_module/data1",
      #                                  "my_module/data2"])]

# This doesn't install it at all.
      package_data = {"my_module" : ["my_module/data1",
                                     "my_module/data2"] }
     )
```

This is in Python 2.7 (will have to run in 2.6 eventually), and will have to run on some Ubuntu between 10.04 and 12+. Developing it right now on 12.04.

Comment: Minimal runnable published working example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed/60735402#60735402

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files

> If directory is a *relative path*, it is interpreted relative to the
>   installation prefix (Python’s sys.prefix for pure-Python packages,
>   sys.exec_prefix for packages that contain extension modules).

This will probably do it:

```
data_files   = [ ("my_module",  ["local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/my_module/data1",
                                 "local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/my_module/data2"])]
```

Or just use join to add the prefix:

```
data_dir = os.path.join(sys.prefix, "local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/my_module")
data_files   = [ ("my_module",  [os.path.join(data_dir, "data1"),
                                 os.path.join(data_dir, "data2")])]
```

Comment: Hmmm. Reluctant to hardcode the path in, but that might serve for now.

Comment: I used distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib() + "path" and used that as the key.

Comment: This is not the proper way to do it. `data_files` is for files you want to put  under /usr (e.g. icons, .desktop files, etc.). If you want to include data along with your Python module you use `package_data` along with the `include_package_data=True` flag.

Comment: I think `sysconfig` attribute is not present in distutils for python2.7 and so is `include_package_data=True` doesnt work

Comment: Various web pages claim that `data_files` locates the installed content somewhere under `sys.prefix`, `sys.exec_prefix`, or `site.USER_BASE`.  I tried it and it dropped them under `/usr`, which is none of those.

Answer (score 23):

**UPD**:
`package_data` accepts dict in format `{'package': ['list', 'of?', 'globs*']}`, so to make it work, one should specify shell globs relative to package dir, not the file paths relative to the distribution root.

`data_files` has a different meaning, and, in general, one should avoid using this parameter.

With setuptools you only need `include_package_data=True`, but data files should be under version control system, known to setuptools (by default it recognizes only CVS and SVN, install `setuptools-git` or `setuptools-hg` if you use git or hg...)

---

with setuptools you can:

<s>- in MANIFEST.im:</s>

```
    include my_module/data*
```

- in setup.py:

```
    setup(
        ...
        include_package_data = True,
        ...
    )
```

Comment: hm. this is a bit short. Can you elaborate on what the respective actions cause? And do I have to do both things or either of them?

Comment: This is the method that worked independent of platform. When I used the accepted answer it worked on Mac OS, but on a Linux VM the data files got copied to strange places.

Comment: When I included `include my_module/data*` inside of the MAINFEST and had `data_files` defined in setup.py, the install did not copy the data files. Removing the data_files definition in setup.py while leaving the include in the MANIFEST resulted in expected behavior.

Comment: include_package_data = True, has generally not worked for me.

Comment: -1: You actually *do* need to use the `data_files` parameter, especially if you're installing from a remote, such as `pip3 install git+https://somesite.com/path/to/repo.git`. Otherwise, the data files *fail* to get included as part of the installation and your program will break (like mine did). So, you need *both* `data_files` and `include_package_data` in your `setup` function.

Comment: @code_dredd this is strange: include_package_data works for me in scenario like yours. What are the versions of pip and setuptools that you use? Maybe it is not git+https but some other kind of remote? pip should clone -d1 the repo to a temporary folder and run setup.py there. Check if running from local folder (`pip install .`) will work properly.

Comment: @podshumok I'm using `pip 9.0.1` for Python3 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (latest at this time). The repository URL is indeed `git+https://...`; I created it (in GitLab) and the remote is correct. It does clone to a `/tmp/...` dir. The thing is, `python3 setup.py build sdist && pip3 install .` would work just fine without having to use `data_files`, but not from a remote -which took some time to figure out. I've read that there're different behaviors depending on the kinds of builds that you do (e.g. `sdist` vs `bdist`), though I don't have a link to such a post at this time or know if it's related.

Comment: @podshumok BTW, to clarify, the `git+` prefix is really necessary if you want `pip` to build and install directly from a URL that points to a Git repository, rather than, say, an existing package from https://pypi.org/

Comment: the OP has a tag `python2.7`, and you guys are discussing w.r.t. `pip3`

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked fine for me. 
You should have MANIFEST.in file where setup.py is located.

Add the following code to the manifest file

```
recursive-include mypackage *.json *.md # can be extended with more extensions or file names.
```

Another solution is adding the following code to the MANIFEST.in file.

```
graft mypackage # will copy the entire package including non-python files. 
global-exclude __pyache__ *.txt # list files you dont want to include here.
```

Now, when you do pip install all the necessary files will be included.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: 
Make sure that you also have `include_package_data=True` in the setup file