# Setup.py is not installing my package_data

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

On both Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 (pip 18.1, python 2.7.15) , I am encountering an issue where I have `package data`  that makes its way into the tar.gz file, but they do not get installed to my scripts directory when I install with pip. My scripts directory on windows is `\Python27\Scripts`. I also checked in `site-packages` and the file doesn't show up there. I want to have a textfile appear alongside the python scripts when installed via pip, and I think that using `data_files` does not achieve this (according to 
 [setup.py not installing data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235820/setup-py-not-installing-data-files) ?

My package structure has all files (`hello.py, MANIFEST.IN, setup.py`)in the one root folder called `fakeapp`. I would like to keep this structure as the project that I actually am trying to fix has this structure.

I have looked up many answers and tried:

- adding an empty `__init__.py` to the root of the repo and this didn't fix it.
- I've tried adding and removing `include_package_files=True` to no avail
- I've tried specifying `package_data={'':['texto.txt']}` as well as
  adding `include texto.txt` to `MANIFEST.in` to no avail.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute?noredirect=1&lq=1): suggests to use bdist, which also didn't work.

I'm sure that this is a duplicate question but I have not been able to get any solution to work.

So here's my test case:
setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    author='hi',
    author_email='hi@hi.com',
    description="test",
    scripts=['hello.py',],
    license='MIT',
    name='hi',
    version='v2018.12.02',
    include_package_data=True
)
```

hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    print('hello world!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

MANIFEST.in:

```
include texto.txt
```

I created a tar.gz in dist/ with

```
python setup.py sdist
```

and my texto.txt is in that tarball.

and then i installed with

```
pip install dist\hi-2018.12.2.tar.gz
```

and only `hello.py` makes its way into `C:\Python2.7\Scripts`

What am I doing wrong?

Directory tree :

```
│   hello.py
│   MANIFEST.in
│   setup.py
│   texto.txt
│
├───dist
│       hi-2018.12.2.tar.gz
│
└───hi.egg-info
        dependency_links.txt
        PKG-INFO
        SOURCES.txt
        top_level.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`texto.txt` is not actually package data, as it is not inside a package (a directory with an `__init__.py`), and thus it will not be installed.  The simplest way to get what you want is to restructure your code so that it installs a package `hello` instead of a flat module `hello.py`, with `hello.py` being moved to `hello/__init__.py` and `texto.txt` being moved to `hello/texto.txt`.

Comment: I'd mentioned in my post that I wanted to retain my directory structure, but your explanation makes sense - thanks! Is there definitely no way that I can get extra files to install via pip while keeping my flat structure?

Comment: @TandyFreeman: The only way to do that would be with the `data_files` `setup()` argument, but the way that pip installs such files is so unfriendly that I recommend against ever using it.

Comment: I might investigate that,looking at other answers it seems that data_files is a bit of a mess. But you've answered my question so I'll tick approved.