# Any python function to get "data_files" root directory?

Tags: python, setup.py

This should be a very common question for developers who used "setup.py" to build installation packages and it should be asked before but I couldn't find the proper answer anywhere.

In setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    ....,
    ....,
    data_files=[('MyApp/CBV', ['myapp/data/CBV/training.cbv', 'myapp/data/CBV/test.cbv'])],
    ....,
    ....,
    )
```

Result of sudo python setup.py install

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/MyApp_trainer to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/MyApp_reference_updater to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/MyApp_predictor to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/reference_updater to 755
running install_data
creating /usr/local/MyApp/CBV
copying MyApp/data/CBV/training.cbv -> /usr/local/MyApp/CBV
copying MyApp/data/CBV/test.cbv -> /usr/local/MyApp/CBV
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MyApp-0.1.0.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MyApp-0.1.0.egg-info
```

From the observation using the result above, "/usr/local" is the "data_files" root directory. Other than hardcoding, are there any Python functions that can give me this "data_files" root directory?

Comment: Minimal runnable published working example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed/60735402#60735402

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, when installing a package as root, *relative* directory names in the `data_files` list are are resolved against either the value of [`sys.prefix`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix) (for pure-python libraries) or [`sys.exec_prefix`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exec_prefix) (for libraries with a compiled extension), so you can retrieve your files based on that. Qouting from the [`distutils` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files):

> If *directory* is a relative path, it is interpreted relative to the installation prefix (Python’s `sys.prefix` for pure-Python packages, `sys.exec_prefix` for packages that contain extension modules).

So for your example, you'll find your files in `os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'MyApp', 'CBV')`.

However, you would be better off using the [`importlib.resources` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) (Python 3.7 and up) to load package data. You do want your data files included in the package for that to work best. That means you would *not* use `data_files` but instead either list file patterns in a MANIFEST.in file and set `include_package_data=True`, or list file patterns in `package_data`, see [*Including data files*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files) in the setuptools documentation.

For earlier Python versions, you can do the same with the [`pkg_resources` module Resource API](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) to load data files (it is part of the `setuptools` library, for this very purpose).

You can then load such resource files straight from the package into a string with `resource_string()` for example:

```
try:
    from importlib.resources import read_text
except ImportError:
    from pkg_resources import resource_string as read_text

foo_config = read_text(__name__, 'foo.conf')
```

Comment: Currently, I'm using "setup" from "distutils". It may take a while to test if your solution can help me :)

Comment: @JessadaThutkawkorapin: Switching to `setuptools` is easy enough. :-) It's backwards compatible to `distutils`, and definitely recommendable!

Comment: While I was looking for the difference between disutils and setuptools, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-and-setuptools. From what I roughly read, it seems like the suggestion was going toward disutils2. Do you still recommend setuptools?

Comment: I still recommend `distribute` (the `setuptools` fork). `distutils2` has yet to materialize. `distribute` is the current defacto standard for python package distribution.

Comment: This `resource_string` doesn't appear to work for `data_files` that specify that the file should appear at root or some subdirectory outside of the package directories.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: no, the Resource API (including `resource_string()`) only works with `include_package_data` / `package_data` files, **not** with `data_files` locations. That's why my answer says *You do want your data files included in the package for that to work best* followed by a link on how to do that.

Comment: sys.prefix doesn't work for me. In a venv sys.prefix gives the venv root which corresponds to the data_files root. Outside venv with the pip lauched as sudo, sys.prefix gives /usr and the data_files root is /usr/local !

Comment: @michael.t: a virtualenv changes the location where stuff gets installed, yes. That’s the purpose of a virtualenv. What you describe is expected behaviour.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters This is obviously OK. The problem is that in a venv `data_files` gets installed in `sys.prefix` and outside a venv it gets installed in `sys.prefix/local`
Considering that the app doesn't know how it has been installed, it cannot know if the `data_files` end up in `sys.prefix` or `sys.prefix/local`.

Comment: @michael.t: I'd have to go deep-dive again why that would be; IIRC I explicitly traced the distutils / setuptools intallation code to determine how `sys.prefix` is being used, and virtualenv basically sets `sys.prefix`. I don't have much time at the moment however :-/

Comment: Great answer, but what about the [editable installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-editable)

Comment: @betontalpfa: this works just the same with an editable installation.

Comment: I mean, the `data_files`, the `sys.prefix` pattern wont work with `data_files` in editable mode

Comment: @betontalpfa: sorry, I see what you mean. Which is why you want to use `importlib.resources` and `package_data`, which works when using editable mode.

Comment: @betontalpfa: the alternative being that you build in a fallback to a relative path to your module to handle the editable case.