# Including static files in a Pypi package

Tags: python, django

I have a Django reusable app, and I am trying to distribute all the static content (html templates etc). After some googling I found out about MANIFEST.in files [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute).

I found a similar project [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/MANIFEST.in) that I used for reference:

`recursive-include allauth *.html *.txt *.xml *.po *.mo *.js`

Here is the contents of my MANIFEST.in:
`recursive-include auth_backend *.html *.scss *.css *.jpg *.png *.js`

I pushed it to Pypi and installed, but there are no static files.
[Here](https://github.com/Kagiso-Future-Media/django_auth) is the source.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
If I download the package as a zip file straight from pypi the templates are included, so it seems the problem is now with pip install...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597263/818951.
What to distribute and what to install are done separate config steps.

I needed to include the following setting:
`include_package_data=True`

to my `setup.py` file