# How to include additional files into a package?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, python-packaging

How can I include files that are not written in python to the packaging?
Or to make it more concrete:
Assuming I have the following package structure, how do I include all the files of the templates directory?

```
- projectname
  - __init__.py
  - classfile.py
  - templates
    - file1.prototxt
    - file2.caffemodel
```

I have the following `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
  name = 'projectname',    
  packages = ['projectname'], 
  version = '0.1',      
  license='MIT',        
  description = 'my description',  
  author = 'FULL NAME',                
  author_email = 'example@gmail.com',     
  url = 'https://github.com/repo',   
  download_url = 'https://github.com/repo/.../v_01.tar.gz',
  keywords = ['keywords'],  
  install_requires=[      
          'opencv-python',
          'numpy'
      ],
  classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',      
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',      
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',  
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',     
  ],
)
```

As I read somewhere on stackoverflow, I tried adding the following to the `setup.py` file but it didn't make a difference.

```
package_data = {
      'templates': ['*'],
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preamble. The word "package" is heavily overloaded. I'll use the word meaning ["importable package"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), i.e. an directory with `__init__.py`.

I see two problems with your code. First, you use `distutils` which is an obsolete outdated package. It will be removed from Python. You should switched to `setuptools` long ago. So replace the line

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

with

```
from setuptools import setup
```

The 2nd problem is in

```
package_data = {
    'templates': ['*'],
}
```

The keys in the dictionary are **packages**, not directory names. Your `templates` is not a package (no `__init__.py`) but a data directory. So the way to include it is

```
package_data = {
    'projectname': ['templates/*'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Potential duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515842/including-static-files-in-a-pypi-package)

```
include_package_data=True
```

Comment: Adding `include_package_data=True` did not solve the issue :/

Comment: Did you check the link that I cited, and the link that they cited? They have more details about the solution, its not just that single line :)

Comment: @Pythoner "*Did you check the link that I cited, and the link that they cited? They have more details about the solution…*" In that case your answer is not an answer. An answer must be self-contained.

Comment: @phd "An answer must be self-contained" -- I am happy to copy the contents of both links and paste them here, but referencing the solution of the duplicate question seemed more efficient.