# How do I distribute my pip package with data files correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

I have a following package to distribute:

```
mymodule/
    data/
        1.txt
    mymodule/
        __init__.py
    tests/
        test_mymodule.py
    setup.py
```

In order to install it under a vitualenv I apply this command:

```
pip install .
```

Everything is installed fine but the path to my data file becomes broken.

```
>>> from mymodule import get
>>> print(get())
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/alexander/Stuff/pip_example/mymodule_test/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mymodule/../data/1.txt'
```

I made a research and found, the folder `data` was create in the root of the virtualenv's folder that caused the error. How should I improve my code to keep my tests working and to have the correct path to the data file?

The contents of the files:

**data/1.txt**

```
yes
```

**mymodule/__init__.py**

```
import os

src = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    '../data/1.txt'
)

def get():
    with open(src) as f:
        return f.read().strip()
```

**tests/test_mymodule.py**

```
import unittest
import mymodule

class MymoduleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get(self):
        s = mymodule.get()
        self.assertEqual(s, "yes")
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup

data_files = [
    ('data', ['data/1.txt'])
]

setup(
    name='mymodule',
    version='0.0',
    packages=['mymodule'],
    data_files=data_files,
)
```

I am new in packaging Python modules. Please help me with this issue.

=====================================================================

I figured out that I need to use `sys.prefix` to access the virtualenv's root. In other words, if I edit **mymodule.__init__.py** this way everything will work correctly:

```
import os
import sys

src = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'data/1.txt')

def get():
    with open(src) as f:
        return f.read().strip()
```

But after that the test fails with the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/data/1.txt'
```

This is because `sys.prefix` is `/usr` without activated virtualenv. So I need a different way to improve the package, I guess.

Comment: Minimal runnable published working example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed/60735402#60735402

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that your file is properly distributed when installing the package.
2. `sys.prefix` will not locate "your" package. The `__file__` attribute of the module points to the `__init__.py` file. You can use this for the base path as in:

   ```
   import os
   import mymodule

   src = os.path.join(os.dirname(mymodule.__file__), 'data/1.txt')

   def get():
       with open(src) as f:
           return f.read().strip()
   ```

Comment: It doesn't work, because after installation the file 1.txt is located in a different place regarding the module (I mentioned it in the question).

Comment: Can you try using the `package_data` argument to `setup` (as in `package_data = {'mymodule': ['data/1.txt']}`. the dict key here is the name of the pacakge and the dict value is a list containing paths that will be installed. This should place the files within the package directory and hence in a known and findable location.

Comment: For this to work, `data` must be *under* `mymodule`, that is in `mymodule/mymodule/data`. The first "mymodule" just happens to be the name of the directory in which the whole project (setup file, doc, etc) is stored. Can you re-try after having moved `data` one level of `mymodule` down?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But what if I want to keep my data file outside the module folder? Isn't it impossible to pack?

Comment: You can do that with distutils (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files)) but setuptools is the recommended tool now and for setuptools it is [impossible](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#non-package-data-files).