# How to publish a project which has mp3 files to pypi?

Tags: python, pypi

I maintain a project that has mp3 files, the structure is like this:

[image]

The xinqing.py is the main file.

My `setup.py` file is written like this:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="xinqing",
    version="0.0.10",
    author="heihei",
    author_email="heihei@hh.com",
    description="A class describes a person.",
    long_description="A class describes a person.",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(include=["xinqing","xinqing/*"]),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>3',
    include_package_data=True

)
```

And my `MANIFEST.in` file is written like this:

```py
recursive-include xinqing/ *.mp3 *.wav
```

I use the mp3 file in the main file in this way:

```py
cur_file_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
cur_file_folder = os.path.dirname(cur_file_path)
mp3_folder = cur_file_folder
mp3_file_path = os.path.join(mp3_folder, "typing_long.mp3")

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound, args=(mp3_file_path,))

# I also tried to use vlc, but they all reported files not found error when I published them to pypi
# sound = vlc.MediaPlayer(os.path.join(mp3_folder,'typing_long.mp3'))
```

When I published them to PyPI, and installed them using `pip install xinqing`, and write code

```py
from xinqing import Xinqing
xq=Xinqing()
xq.do_what()
```

Then will report the files not found error.

The commands that I published them to PyPI are

```sh
python setup.py bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
```

I think the reason is that I do not handle the mp3 source files correctly.

**So how to resolve this problem?**

Comment: See [manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed/3597263#3597263)

Comment: Wow, perfect!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, thanks for the answer provided by InsertCheesyLine, thank you!.
It's easy,just add one line code

```py
data_files=[('xinqing',['xinqing/typing_long.mp3'])],
```

in the setup.py file.

More detailed information can be got from the page https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data.