# Using setuptools with pyproject.toml ignores my bash script

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml, setuptools-scm

I am using setuptools with pyproject.toml and setuptools_scm. I think setuptools is not working correctly, but functionality has changed so much and the documentation doesn't seem to explain the problem I'm having, so I'm kind of lost here. I want to be able to run `pip install <path to my package root>` and have the my bash script copied into the installed path, here `.local/lib/pythonversion/site-packages/duck/`. The `duck` package structure is:

```
duck/
    pyproject.toml
    README.md
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
    duck/
        __init__.py
        duck (shell script)
        quack/
            ...
        flap/
            ...
```

From the `duck` root directory, I run `pip install .` and  I see from the duck.egg-info that `setuptools_scm` is listing my "duck" bash script.

After the install completes, the `duck` script is not in `.local/lib/python3.8/duck/`.

I've tried explicitly listing the file using `MANIFEST.in` but that has no effect, apparently.

My `pyproject.toml` is very simple:

```
[build-system]
requires   = ["setuptools>=45", "setuptools_scm[toml]>6.2"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
[tools.setuptools_scm]
```

My `setup.cfg` is also simple:

```
[metadata]
name = duck
description = A very quacky package

[options]
install_requires=
    pandas>=1.4
    ...
```

Finally, I do have `setup.py` so that I can specify setuptools:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(use_scm_version=True)
```

**What I have tried**

- Created a MANIFEST.in and explicitly included `duck` the bash script
- Using [package_data] directive to specify the files
- Using [data_files] directive
- I also thought that using [project.scripts] would be a good idea, but that is specifically designed for Python entrypoints.

According to [the documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) it suffices to specify `[tool.setuptools]` in your `pyproject.toml` when you're using a VCS, and (I quote) *[...] will be automatically installed with your package*. I know the context is a little bit vague, but what I **infer** from reading the documentation is that my .toml file is sufficient to install all these git tracked files.

I can start from scratch and put all this functionality into my `setup.py`, but this seems (to me) like a very simple use case that setuptools not getting right.

I am hoping there is something small and/or obvious that I am either doing wrong or can change to fix this. Failing that, I will write the full `setup.py`.

Comment: This question would be improved if you provided exactly what you tried.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3596979/9374673)? Is there something different about your use case that's not covered in that one?

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Yes, I'm using pyproject.toml -- which I may have to switch over to just using setup.py