# Imported code cannot open files in its directory

Tags: python, import

I have the following file structure:

```
test/
    test1.py
test2.py
text.txt
```

Here are the contents of the files

**test1.py:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import test2

test2.read()
```

**test2.py:**

```
def read():
    with open('text.txt', 'rb') as f:
        print f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read()
```

`text.txt` contains a line of text. When I run `test1.py`, I get a "File not found" error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    test2.read()
  File "../test2.py", line 2, in read
    with open('text.txt', 'rb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'
```

I kind of understand why this error is coming up. But how do I deal with these kind of errors. I would like the code in `test2.py` to be like library code which I can use anywhere.

Comment: This isn't actually the right path to add to `sys.path` in the first place. This adds the parent directory of the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). What you want to add is the parent of the directory _that `test1.py` is in_. Those _could_ be the same thing, but there's no guarantee they will be. For example, if you're sitting in the parent directory in the shell, you can always run `python test/test1.py`, and then everything will break.

Comment: @abarnert excuse my ignorance, but how can we add the parent of test1.py's directory?

Comment: The safest way to do it (in 2.7) is: `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. (The `abspath` in there in case you `chdir` later on. The key part of it is starting from wherever `__file__` is—that is, the `test1.py` script—instead of wherever the working directory is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way of doing what you're asking for is to use pkg_resources as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39659). Basically something like the following would be what you want in test2.py:

```
import pkg_resources

def read():
    with pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, 'text.txt') as f:
        print f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read()
```

Comment: Assuming you want to build this as a package to be installed (or built into a binary via `cx_Freeze`, or wrapped up in a deb/rpm, or…), this is the right answer. And usually, for anything more complicated than a single script, you _do_ want that. Being able to run out of the source tree is, at best, a "nice to have"; being able to run when installed is critical.

Comment: @abarnert I'm not sure what you guys are criticizing. This does not require that the package be installed. I just tried this by creating the test2.py file inside a package called test2, running python, doing import test2.test2; test2.test2.read() and it worked for me. Are you saying that doesn't work for some people?

Answer (score 5):

`sys.path` used for python path (`PYTHONPATH` eviroment variable).
i.e. where to look for python libraries when you `import` some library. 
it dose not effect where `open()` is looking for files.

when you `open(filename)`. the `filename` is relative to the procees [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). (the path the code was run from)

so if you want to access a flie that its path is relative to the path of the code file, then you can use the builtin variable `__file__` which hold the current file path.

so you can change `test2.py` to be:

```
import os

def read():
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'text.txt'), 'rb') as f:
        print f.read()
```

Comment: But, I will still need to use `sys.path.append()` for importing `test2.py` right?

Comment: Note that, although this is definitely the "right" way to do it, it won't work if you ever `chdir` while your app is running, and there are various edge cases where it doesn't actually work right (e.g., `__file__` ends up as `test2.py`—that's fixed in 3.4, where `__file__` is guaranteed to be an absolute path no matter what, but that doesn't help for 2.7).

Comment: Also, I think mentioning the concept of ["current working directory"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) with that Wikipedia link or some better link might make this clearer than just "where you run the code from". Because as written, it implies that the directory that `test1.py` lives in is what matters, and that isn't true.

Comment: @abarnert I would argue that my solution actually the "right" way of doing it.

Comment: @Phani right, if `test2.py` path is not already in your `PYTHONPATH` then you still need to `sys.path.append()` it

Comment: @CrazyCasta: Yes, if you can rely on your script being installed rather than run out of source (and are willing to either require `setuptools` or do the bootstrap thing, but I can't see why you wouldn't be willing to bootstrap it), `pkg_resources` is the best answer.

Comment: @CrazyCasta, the problem with your suggestion is that it will break on different installation or when you copy your program to another location.

Comment: @Elisha: The whole point of using `setuptools` and installing (to site-packages, or to a binary distribution of some kind, or whatever) is to make that problem irrelevant. The top-level script(s) end up on your PATH, and refer to your modules, and can be moved around freely; those modules end up in your `site-packages` or similar and never get moved around. Moving to a different installation is done by installing the same package on the new installation.

Comment: @abarnert @CrazyCasta My code is more like ongoing research work which will not come to a "packaged" state any time soon. So, most of the time I will be running out of source. Can I use `pkg_resources` in this case?

Comment: @Phani: Even for ongoing research work, making it into an installable package makes all kinds of things easier for you. It means you can use `setuptools`. It means you can have 28 forked or branched versions of the source that all share the same data files. You can add a Cython or C extension trivially, while doing it manually without `setup.py` is a nightmare. You can document and automate your dependencies, so moving to a new machine or upgrading to a new Python is easy. And so on.

Comment: @Phani AFAIK you can use pkg_resources even if you don't plan on installing it. I may be wrong as I'm not all that familiar with it, but that's my understanding.

Comment: My comments here about @CrazyCasta answer are irrelevant. I mixed up with his answer and @ alKid's by mistake

Comment: @Elisha Lol, now it all makes sense at least :P

Answer (score 0):

Don't use relative path, then. Use the full path:

```
with open(r'C:\Somewhere\someplace\test.txt') as f:
```

Comment: That is not the correct full path. `..` means "go up a directory".

Comment: I want this to be part of a project that I run from multiple places, is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Hm.. The code is _imported_ to `test1` script. So the one looking for the script is `test1`, not `test2`. I'll update my answer in a sec.

Comment: This isn't likely to work well for "library code" if he wants to redistribute it.

Comment: There's also the fact that this path has a tab character in it, not a backslash and a `t`…