# __init__.py reads a file inside a module which fails when top module is zipped

Tags: python, io, python-3.6, configuration-files, python-packaging

I have code that reads a configuration file in a `__init__.py` file inside a certain module. Let's say I have a structure like this:

```
dir/
    setup.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        properties/
           config.yaml
        module/
           __init__.py ---> this file reads src/properties/config.yaml
```

The code to read is something like this:

```
with open(os.path.join(_ROOT, os.path.normpath('src/properties/config.yaml'))) as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)
```

Where `_ROOT` is defined in the top `src/__init__.py` as follows:

```
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Basically, `_ROOT=dir`.

This works like a charm in every platform, except when `src` is used as a zip package on which reading returns a `FileNotFoundError: ... No such file or directory: ... package.zip\\src\\properties\\config.yaml`.

Is there a way to address this problem, do I need to deal the situation when package is zipped, should I avoid loading the file inside the package code...?

I tried an extensive google search for this but I found nothing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104/finding-a-file-in-a-python-module-distribution?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with `pkgutil.get_data`!

```
import src
a = pkgutil.get_data('src', 'properties/config.yaml')
config = yaml.load(a)
```

Et voilá!